# Difference between constructor in ES6 class and constructor in prototype?

Tags: javascript, class, constructor, prototypal-inheritance, es6-class

Both ES6 class and prototype of function have a `contructor`, but I'm wondering are they the same? Let me give more explanations.

So, I create a Cat function, for instance:

```
const Cat = function (name) {
    this.name = name;
};
```

The Cat has the following prototype:
[image]
This `constructor` can be lost if I type smth. like `Cat.prototype = {};`, but `new Cat('Name');` will continue working.
Ang we have the following syntax in ES6:

```
class Dog {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

The class also has `constructor` and it looks just like a simple function. Since classes are just a syntactic sygar over prototype inheritance, is the constructor function in Dog class is just the same as in Cat function or these are different concepts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since classes are just a syntactic sugar over prototype inheritance, is the constructor function in Dog class just the same as in Cat function?

Yes, the constructor-prototype relationship still works the same.

There are a few differences though, for example `Dog.prototype` is not writable and `Dog` can only be called with `new`.